# How to select the objects by only clicking the actual contents by Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I want to select the objects by clicking the actual contents. So I set the `perPixelTargetFind=true` and following the paragraph in the introduction:

> "By default, all `Fabric` objects on canvas can be dragged by the bounding box. However, if you want different behavior — clicking/dragging objects only by its actual contents, you can use "`perPixelTargetFind`" property on an object. Just set it to true to get the desired behavior."

By doing this, I can drag the objects by the actual contents, but the objects can still be selected by clicking the bounding area.

Is it possible to clicking objects only by its actual contents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Is this what you wanted?**](http://fabricjs.com/per-pixel-drag-drop)

```
for (var i = 0, len = 15; i < len; i++) {
    fabric.Image.fromURL('../assets/ladybug.png', function(img) {
        img.set({
            left: fabric.util.getRandomInt(0, 600),
            top: fabric.util.getRandomInt(0, 500),
            angle: fabric.util.getRandomInt(0, 90)
        });

        img.perPixelTargetFind = true;
        img.targetFindTolerance = 4;
        img.hasControls = img.hasBorders = false;

        img.scale(fabric.util.getRandomInt(50, 100) / 100);

        canvas.add(img);
    });
}
```

Basically, you assign **perPixelTargetFind** is true, and (**hasControls** & **hasBorders**) is false.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. In this way, there will be no bounding area. But controls like Rotating and Scaling are disabled. I still need these features. Is it possible that the bounding box appears only when the object contents are clicked?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/S9sLu/

As you can see in this example, the bounding box, only appears when clicked on. It's there by default.
Do accept and upvote my answer if it helped you out.

Comment: Thanks very much. This almost solved my question. :) But in the example from your answer, the property "selection" is set as "false".  While if I set "selection" as "true", the bounding box appears if I click the area that does not include actual object content. I need "selection" to be "true" so that more than one objects can be selected simultaneously. Is it possible to set "selection" as "true" and bounding box appears only when the actual object contents are clicked?